# Efficient word frequency count in python for large scale processing in a single machine

Tags: python, word-frequency

I have a huge text file with string content. My use case is to identify the words and its corresponding count.

In python, a normal way to achieve this is to use a **dictionary** and keep track of word and its count. There is also another way of using **Collections Counter** to find out the most common words.

The above approaches works fine, but it is not space efficient as the size of the dict will be the total number of unique words.
Is there any other efficient algorithm to find out the cardinality of words for large data in a single machine? i.e. without using distributed computing like Hadoop Map reduce or Spark?

Comment: Did you run into a memory issue (which would be surprising), or are you simply wondering whether there's a way to note how many times any given word has appeared without keeping track of that value (there isn't)?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that a modified tokenizing method can yield multi-word tokens which can easily lead to a dictionary size much greater than 10**6.
Since the solution requested seems to be concerned only with storing all tokens in memory, a Trie based storage instead of a dict may suffice.

Check out [hat-trie](https://github.com/kmike/hat-trie) which says

> For keys that share prefixes it usually uses less memory than Python
>   dict.

There would be some sacrifice of speed though. Other such data structures include datrie, marisa-trie and DAWG.

You could multiprocess to speed up the counting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think you can get around storing the total number of unique words one way or the other. `collections.Counter` would probably be the simplest way to do it, as you mentioned.

If memory usage is a problem, you can try storing the results in a numpy array, although it is not very suitable/optimal for this particular case.

Also no matter how large dataset is, there are only [`10**6` unique words in English](http://www.languagemonitor.com/number-of-words/number-of-words-in-the-english-language-1008879/) (and probably only 10% of those are actively used), so assuming an average length of 10 characters per words, with 1 byte per characters, the corresponding memory size would be only be ~10 MB in C and say maybe ~100MB accounting for the Python overhead and unicode.  Actually, generating a dict with 10**6 random 10 character long words, takes  115 MB, so it shouldn't be a problem to store on any modern system.

```
In [14]: import string
    ...: import random
    ...: import itertools
    ...: %load_ext memory_profiler
    ...:
    ...: def gen_dict(n):
    ...:     out = {}
    ...:     for i, name in enumerate(itertools.product(string.letters, repeat=10)):
    ...:         if i > n: break
    ...:         out[''.join(name)] = random.randint(0, N)
    ...:     return out
    ...:
    ...: N = 1000000
    ...: %memit x = gen_dict(N)
    ...: print(len(x.keys()))
    ...: 
peak memory: 150.45 MiB, increment: 116.52 MiB
1000001
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there any intuitive way to use bitset method to find the cardinality of words?